# Find and print the total number of pairs such that ai*aj <= max(ai,ai+1,.....aj) where i < j. Python Recursion Issues with Large Input Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I'm working on a Python function that is supposed to solve a problem involving a large input array. The function uses recursion, and I've encountered performance issues with large input arrays.

**Below is the problem statement and code** :

**Description** : Consider an array of n integers, A = [a1, a2,..., an]. Find and print the total number of (i, j) pairs such that ai × aj ≤ max(ai, ai+1,..., aj) where i < j.

**Input Format**
The first line contains an integer, n, denoting the number of elements in the array. The second line consists of n space-separated integers describing the respective values of a1, a2,.. an.

**Constraints**

- 1 <= n <= 5 * 10 ^ 5
- 1 <= a_{i} <= 10 ^ 9

**Scoring**

- 1 <= n <= 1000 for 25% of the test cases.
- 1 <= n <= 10 ^ 5 for 50% of the test cases.
- 1 <= n <= 5 * 10 ^ 5 for 100% of the test cases.

**Output Format**
Print a long integer denoting the total number (i, j) pairs satisfying a; xa; max(a₁, a₁+1,..., aj)
where i < j.

**Sample Input**
5
1 1 2 4 2

**Sample Output**
8

**Explanation**
There are eight pairs of indices satisfying the given criteria: (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2,5), and (3, 5). Thus, we print 8 as our answer.

**Here is my solution** :

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

#
# Complete the 'solve' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return a LONG_INTEGER.
# The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY arr as parameter.
#

def solve(arr):
    # Write your code here
    if len(arr)<=1:
        return 0

    indx=arr.index(max(arr))

    x= solve(arr[0:indx+1] if indx != len(arr)-1 else arr[0:indx]) + solve(arr[indx+1:])

    arr=sorted(arr[0:indx+1])+sorted(arr[indx+1:])

    i=indx-1 if indx == len(arr)-1 else indx
    j=indx+1 if indx !=len(arr)-1 else indx

    while i>=0 and j<len(arr):
        p=arr[i]*arr[j]
        if p <= arr[indx]:
            x+=i+1
            j+=1
        else:
            i-=1

    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    arr_count = int(input().strip())
    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    result = solve(arr)
    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

I just had to make changes to the solve function.

**Here's the test cases where my code is failing** :

- The test case where **arr contains all 100,000 values**, it's likely due to the recursive nature of solve function. Python has a recursion depth limit, and it's possible that the recursion depth is exceeded for large input arrays.
- The test case where **arr contains values 1 to 500,000 with odd indices as 2** may also be failing due to a time limit issue

**How to optimize my code so that these two test cases passes ?**

Comment: Can you explain in words what your algo is currently (supposed to be) doing? In particular, I don't think putting the sorted first and second half into one list `arr` will work, but you should keep it as two separate lists (not about performance but correctness).

Comment: The algorithm recursively splits the input list into smaller sublists based on the maximum element's index, sorts these sublists, and then iteratively calculates the number of pairs whose product is less than or equal to the maximum element in the original list. It accumulates these counts and returns the final result.

Comment: @Barmar That would get rid of the slicing, but I think the sorting still makes sense, at least that _should_ be something like O(n(logn)²) or so, whereas without sorting you'd have to check all pairs of numbers in the segment?

Comment: If there are test cases with a large, sorted (or almost-sorted) list your algorithm will probably be quite slow on those, since its runtime complexity degrades to at least O(n²) in that case.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen.. Yeah Indeed

Comment: The maximum recursion depth of your algorithm depends on the position of the maximum value in `arr`. For example, if the input is in ascending order, `indx` is always `len(arr) - 1` and the maximum depth is `n`. When `n=5*10^5`, to keep the maximum depth within 1000 (which is the limit in my environment), the split ratio must be at worst 1:77. If there is such a malicious test case (and if you are not allowed to change the recursion depth limit), you would need more drastic changes.

Comment: Can you explain more about what test cases you're expecting to deal with? I don't understand what you've written currently. Will they be adversarial? On my system, the input `list(range(1, 30000))` takes over 5 seconds, and it crashes on `list(range(1, 50000))`, even with a heightened recursion limit. Do you expect to deal with inputs like this, even for the largest values of n? Do you know roughly what sort of run-time is acceptable? There's a fair bit of tuning you can do, but if you need it to run in much less than five minutes on an input like that you'll have to avoid the O(n^2) somehow.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-pairs/problem
You can read about the problem and test cases from here

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen If there are no adverserial test cases, then the problem setter didn't do their job.

Comment: @KellyBundy, it looks like at least the largest test cases on hackerrank are not designed to induce quadratic behaviour. I think it's a bit extreme to say that means the problem setter didn't do their job! Perhaps there is no known significantly better algorithm. I think it's valid for the problem setter's intention to be "write an algorithm that performs well with high probability", even if that's a bit unconventional in eg competitive programming, it can still be a valuable exercise.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I've been a problem setter myself. If quadratic is the best they know, then they should've lowered the limits instead of not properly testing the limits.

Comment: @KellyBundy, that's fair enough. Of course you're right that it's unusual for the test cases to be like this. Sorry for coming off as a bit argumentative! I suppose that my thinking is that there is a meaningful sense in which eg the naïve implementation of quicksort is still a "better" algorithm than bubblesort, even though they have the same worst-case complexity. Nevertheless it's all a bit academic, as I've realised there is a nice subquadratic (in fact quasi-linear, of course) algorithm to solve this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a hard question, and you've already come up with a very good
idea for an algorithm.

However, it can still be refined and optimised a bit further, both practically
and algorithmically. I will discuss and implement some of these improvements.

My discussion of time complexity will be a bit informal - when I analyse "the
average case", what I mean is that I'm making the assumption that the maximum
always occurs somewhere close to the middle (or if you like, there is some
constant 0 < c < 50 such that the maximum never occurs in the first or last c%
of the array). In the average case, your algorithm
currently takes O(n (log n)²) time, which is pretty good!

In the worst case, for example when the input is sorted or nearly-sorted, it
degenerates to O(n²). There are changes you can make to improve on the current
extremal worst cases, as well as changes that avoid quadratic behaviour
altogether (see the later part of my answer). There is an optimisation that
causes sorted or reverse-sorted inputs to be solvable faster. It also cleans up
your edge case logic, and reduces the size of the required call stack by a
factor of about 2!

Namely, instead of splitting the array into `arr[:indx + 1]` and
`arr[indx + 1:]` with special logic for if `indx` was the largest index in the
array, you can split into `arr[:indx]` and `arr[indx + 1:]`. Now this means that
compared to your code, we will not yet have counted pairs `i`, `j` with
`j == indx`. But since we know that the entries in the array are positive integers, this
is exactly the same as the number of `j` with `arr[j] == 1`. We can find these
in constant time given a cheap O(n) pre-computation step where we store the
number of `1`s in each prefix of the array. If we're doing that step anyway, we
can also use this to find the number of pairs `i`, `j` with `i == indx`, making the
subsequent search just for pairs with `i < indx < j`.

Another part that can be sped up is the search for the maximum. In the average
case, about O(n log n) time is spent on this, but in the worst case, about
O(n²) time is spent on this. We can improve on this by implementing a
[segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). We can build the
tree in O(n) time, and then subsequently each query takes O(log n) time, so even
in the worst case of a sorted or nearly-sorted list, only O(n log n) time will
be spent searching for the maximum. In combination with the optimisation from
the previous paragraph, this means sorted and reverse-sorted inputs will now
take O(n log n) time. This relies on the observation that we can merge a sorted
array with an empty array in constant time. (However, inputs like `[1, n + 1, 2, n + 2, 3, n + 3, ..., n, n + n]` still take O(n²) time, and to avoid this you
need some even heavier machinery.)

If we assign a random tie-break number to each element of the array to determine
which index the segment tree returns as the maximum, the algorithm will also run
much faster with high probability for inputs with many duplicate entries, such
as `[1, 1, 1, ..., 1]` or `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...]`.

The comments already mentioned that you spend a lot of time creating slices of
the array. Each time you slice that creates a whole new copy of that part of the
array, so instead you can pass around a `start` and `end` parameter and modify
the rest of your code so that `arr[0]` becomes `arr[start]` and so on.

There doesn't seem to be any getting around the sorting step as far as I can
tell, which is taking a lot of time. However, we can actually save a factor of
`log n` on this step. Since you sort both the left and right subarray in each
function call, you can sort all of `arr[start:end]` from that point in only
`O(end - start)` time, using the standard merging procedure as in "merge sort".
So the algorithm in effect becomes a sort of merge sort with some extra steps,
and this gets the average case complexity down to O(n log n). The former
worst-case scenario of a sorted list now also takes O(n log n) time! This
improvement carries over to several other scenarios which were previously
catastrophic, such as an input which is a concatenation of a small number of
sorted arrays.

In practice, writing your own implementation of merging is not worth it in
Python, and it's faster to concatenate the two sorted arrays and call
`list.sort` on that. Python's `list.sort` uses TimSort, which runs in linear
time on inputs like this, so there is no loss of asymptotic performance.

For even better performance in practice, it's probably worth switching from
these nice asymptotic approaches (segment trees etc) to a simpler approach
(finding the maximum by doing a pass over the whole array, or even just finding
all pairs `i`, `j` by brute force) for sufficiently small inputs. I've
implemented both of these strategies and done a small amount of testing to
determine sensible points at which to switch.

My segment tree implementation is a bit more optimised than the totally naïve
implementation - querying only requires a constant number of function calls.
Some things could be optmised further, like inlining every helper function and
so on, but that way madness lies - if you need performance that badly, you'd be
better off learning a different programming language.

Here are all of my suggestions together:

```
import random

from itertools import accumulate

# build a segment tree, represented in the standard way as an array, where
# the children of tree[root] are tree[2 * root + 1] and tree[2 * root + 2].
# complexity: O(n) space and O(n) time to build.
def build_segtree(arr):
    if arr:
        tree = [None] * (len(arr) * 4)
        _build_segtree(arr, 0, len(arr), tree, 0)
        return tree
    return []

# tree[root] stores max(arr[start:end]), a random tiebreaker, and the index at
# which the maximum occurs.
def _build_segtree(arr, start, end, tree, root):
    if end - start == 1:
        tree[root] = arr[start], random.random(), start
    else:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        tree[root] = max(
                _build_segtree(arr, start, mid, tree, root * 2 + 1),
                _build_segtree(arr, mid, end, tree, root * 2 + 2))
    return tree[root]

# return max(arr[a:b]), given that root stores information about arr[start:end],
# and start <= a < b <= end.
# Also returns the root of the last subtree with start <= a < b <= end (as from
# that point on, you can always skip to that subtree)
# complexity: O(log(end - start))
def query_segtree(tree, root, start, end, a, b):
    while b - a < end - start:
        mid = (start + end) >> 1
        if mid <= a:
            root = (root << 1) + 2
            start = mid
        elif b <= mid:
            root = (root << 1) + 1
            end = mid
        else:
            return (max(
                query_segtree_suffix(tree, (root << 1) + 1, start, mid, a),
                query_segtree_prefix(tree, (root << 1) + 2, mid, end, b)),
                (tree, root, start, end))
    return tree[root], (tree, root, start, end)

# the special case where b == end.
def query_segtree_suffix(tree, root, start, end, a):
    acc = (-1,)
    while start < a:
        mid = (start + end) >> 1
        if mid <= a:
            root = (root << 1) + 2
            start = mid
        else:
            acc = max(acc, tree[(root << 1) + 2])
            root = (root << 1) + 1
            end = mid
    return max(tree[root], acc)

# the special case where a == start.
def query_segtree_prefix(tree, root, start, end, b):
    acc = (-1,)
    while b < end:
        mid = (start + end) >> 1
        root = (root << 1) + 1
        if b <= mid:
            end = mid
        else:
            acc = max(acc, tree[root])
            root += 1
            start = mid
    return max(acc, tree[root])

# wrapper for _solve3
def solve(arr, thresh=4, thresh2=100):
    # onecount[i] is the number of times 1 appears in arr[:i]
    onecount = list(accumulate(map((1).__eq__, arr), initial=0))
    segtree = build_segtree(arr)
    return _solve3(arr, 0, len(arr), thresh, thresh2, onecount, (segtree, 0, 0, len(arr)))[0]

# returns a pair (x, a)
# where x is the number of valid pairs i, j in the range [start:end]
# and a == sorted(arr[start:end]).
# treedata is the arguments that query_segtree expects to receive.
def _solve3(arr, start, end, thresh, thresh2, onecount, treedata):
    # for small subarrays, use the naive O(n²) approach.
    if end - start <= thresh:
        total_pairs = 0
        for i in range(start, end - 1):
            curr_max = arr[i]
            for j in range(i + 1, end):
                curr_max = max(arr[j], curr_max)
                total_pairs += arr[i] * arr[j] <= curr_max
        return total_pairs, sorted(arr[start:end])
    # for small-ish subarrays, find the maximum by a linear time search.
    if end - start <= thresh2:
        indx = max(range(start, end), key=arr.__getitem__)
        maxval = arr[indx]
    else:
        (maxval, _, indx), treedata = query_segtree(*treedata, start, end)
    x1, arr_left = _solve3(arr, start, indx, thresh, thresh2, onecount, treedata)
    x2, arr_right = _solve3(arr, indx + 1, end, thresh, thresh2, onecount, treedata)
    x = x1 + x2 - onecount[start] + onecount[end] - (maxval == 1)
    if arr_left and arr_right:
        i = indx - 1 - start
        j = 0
        while i >= 0 and j < (end - indx - 1):
            if arr_left[i] * arr_right[j] <= maxval:
                x += i + 1
                j += 1
            else:
                i -= 1
        if indx - start > end - indx - 1:
            arr_left, arr_right = arr_right, arr_left
        arr_left.extend(arr_right)
        arr_left.append(maxval)
        arr_left.sort()
        return x, arr_left
    sorted_arr = arr_left or arr_right
    sorted_arr.append(maxval)
    return x, sorted_arr
```

When I submit this to hackerrank, it says I get 100 points, so I think this is
all the optimisation you need (probably it's a bit more - I wrote most of this
before I knew about the hackerrank problem, so I don't know exactly at what
stage it starts being fast enough).

With some very informal, rough timings, it's anywhere between about 2.5-3 times
as fast as your code for "average-case" inputs and near-sorted inputs, up to
basically infinitely faster (by this I mean it's about 50 times faster for the
size I tested, and for bigger sizes I didn't feel like waiting for `solve` to
terminate) for sorted inputs, because of the n² vs n log n
difference. (Here `solve3` is the name of my version.)

```
[nav] In [3]: sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 6)
         ...: arr = list(chain.from_iterable((i, 2000 + i) for i in range(1, 2000)))
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve3(arr)
231 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [4]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve(arr)
758 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [5]: arr = list(range(1, 500000))
         ...: random.shuffle(arr)
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve3(arr)
1.23 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [6]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve(arr)
3.26 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [7]: arr = list(range(1, 500000))
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve3(arr)
1.92 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [8]: arr = list(range(1, 5000))
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve3(arr)
19.5 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [9]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve(arr)
1.02 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

---

We can however optimise further still. The current major bottleneck in the worst
case is looking for pairs `i`, `j` in the case when the left and right subarrays
are lopsided. We can make this much faster by using a data structure that
supports range queries for elements less than some upper bound `k`. We can use
another type of segment tree to do this, as alluded to in
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39797537/5468953) answer.

This will allow us, for each `i < indx`, to find the number of `j > indx` such
that `i`, `j` is a valid pair in time O((log n)²). Apparently this can be
brought down to O(log n) if you really want, using fractional cascading, but
that's fairly complicated.

We no longer need to do any sorting if we implement this. The worst-case
complexity seems quite delicate to analyse, but I think it becomes
O(n (log n)³). It's important that if the right subarray is smaller, then you
instead iterate over the right subarray and query the tree to count elements in
the left subarray. Here it is, implemented:

```
import random
import bisect
import itertools

... <same segtree functoins as before>

# a segment tree which stores sorted segments of arr. Takes O(n log n) space and
# O(n log n) time to build.
def build_mergetree(arr):
    if arr:
        tree = [None] * (len(arr) * 4)
        _build_mergetree(arr, 0, len(arr), tree, 0)
        return tree
    return []

# tree[root] stores sorted(arr[start:end])
def _build_mergetree(arr, start, end, tree, root):
    if end - start == 1:
        tree[root] = [arr[start]]
    else:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        tree[root] = (
                _build_mergetree(arr, start, mid, tree, root * 2 + 1) +
                _build_mergetree(arr, mid, end, tree, root * 2 + 2))
        tree[root].sort()
    return tree[root]

# return len([x for x in arr[a:b] if x < k]),
# given that root stores information about arr[start:end],
# and start <= a < b <= end.
# complexity: O(log²(b - a) + log(end - start))
def query_mergetree(tree, root, start, end, a, b, k):
    while b - a < end - start:
        mid = (start + end) >> 1
        if mid <= a:
            root = (root << 1) + 2
            start = mid
        elif b <= mid:
            root = (root << 1) + 1
            end = mid
        else:
            return (
                query_mergetree_suffix(tree, (root << 1) + 1, start, mid, a, k)
            + query_mergetree_prefix(tree, (root << 1) + 2, mid, end, b, k))
    return bisect.bisect_left(tree[root], k)

# the special case where b == end.
# complexity: O(log²(b - a))
def query_mergetree_suffix(tree, root, start, end, a, k):
    acc = 0
    while start < a:
        mid = (start + end) >> 1
        if mid <= a:
            root = (root << 1) + 2
            start = mid
        else:
            acc += bisect.bisect_left(tree[(root << 1) + 2], k)
            root = (root << 1) + 1
            end = mid
    return acc + bisect.bisect_left(tree[root], k)

# the special case where a == start.
# complexity: O(log²(b - a))
def query_mergetree_prefix(tree, root, start, end, b, k):
    acc = 0
    while b < end:
        mid = (start + end) >> 1
        root = (root << 1) + 1
        if b <= mid:
            end = mid
        else:
            acc += bisect.bisect_left(tree[root], k)
            root += 1
            start = mid
    return acc + bisect.bisect_left(tree[root], k)

# wrapper for _solve
def solve(arr, thresh=4, thresh2=100, thresh3=300):
    # onecount[i] is the number of times 1 appears in arr[:i]
    onecount = list(itertools.accumulate(map((1).__eq__, arr), initial=0))
    segtree = build_segtree(arr)
    mtree = build_mergetree(arr)
    treedata = (segtree, 0, 0, len(arr))
    return _solve(arr, 0, len(arr), thresh, thresh2, thresh3, onecount, treedata, mtree)[0]

# returns the number of valid pairs i, j in the range [start:end]
# Also returns the root position of the smallest subtree of the segment trees
# that stores information about arr[start:end].
# treedata is the arguments that query_segtree expects to receive.
def _solve(arr, start, end, thresh, thresh2, thresh3, onecount, treedata, mtree):
    # for small subarrays, use the naive O(n²) approach.
    if end - start <= thresh:
        total_pairs = 0
        for i in range(start, end - 1):
            curr_max = arr[i]
            for j in range(i + 1, end):
                curr_max = max(arr[j], curr_max)
                total_pairs += arr[i] * arr[j] <= curr_max
        return total_pairs, treedata
    # find the index of the maximum element using the segment tree
    # for small-ish subarrays, find the maximum by a linear time search.
    if end - start <= thresh2:
        indx = max(range(start, end), key=arr.__getitem__)
        maxval = arr[indx]
    else:
        (maxval, _, indx), treedata = query_segtree(*treedata, start, end)
    # the number of valid pairs in arr[start:indx]
    x1, (_, *ldata) = _solve(arr, start, indx, thresh, thresh2, thresh3, onecount, treedata, mtree)
    # the number of valid pairs in arr[indx + 1:start]
    x2, (_, *rdata) = _solve(arr, indx + 1, end, thresh, thresh2, thresh3, onecount, treedata, mtree)
    # the number of valid pairs involving arr[indx]
    x = x1 + x2 - onecount[start] + onecount[end] - (maxval == 1)
    if (end - indx + 5) * (indx - start + 6) <= thresh3:
        # print(start, indx, indx + 1, end)
        x += sum(1 for i, j in itertools.product(range(start, indx), range(indx + 1, end))
                if arr[i] * arr[j] <= maxval)
        return x, treedata
    # now calculate the remaining pairs, using the mergetree
    if indx - start < end - (indx + 1):
        for i in range(start, indx):
            # the number of elements arr[j] of arr[indx + 1:start]
            # for which arr[j] * arr[i] <= maxval.
            # or equivalently, arr[j] < 1 + maxval // arr[i]
            cutoff = 1 + maxval // arr[i]
            x += query_mergetree(mtree, *rdata, indx + 1, end, cutoff)
    else:
        for j in range(indx + 1, end):
            cutoff = 1 + maxval // arr[j]
            x += query_mergetree(mtree, *ldata, start, indx, cutoff)
    return x, treedata
```

While this performs better on the very worst-case inputs, its performance in the
average case is a bit worse (and Hackerrank won't accept it!) The new worst
case is also actually what was previously the best case - if the maximum occurs
near the middle in a large number of the subarrays we look at. So a further
optimisation is to use a mixture of both of these algorithms, depending on the
position of the maximum. This can give us the best of both worlds.

```
...(same as before)

# wrapper for _solve
def solve(arr, thresh=4, thresh2=100, thresh3=300, mixthresh=0.1):
    # onecount[i] is the number of times 1 appears in arr[:i]
    onecount = list(itertools.accumulate(map((1).__eq__, arr), initial=0))
    segtree = build_segtree(arr)
    mtree = build_mergetree(arr)
    treedata = (segtree, 0, 0, len(arr))
    return _solve(arr, 0, len(arr), thresh, thresh2, thresh3, mixthresh, onecount, treedata, mtree)[0]

# returns the number of valid pairs i, j in the range [start:end]
# Also returns the root position of the smallest subtree of the segment trees
# that stores information about arr[start:end].
# treedata is the arguments that query_segtree expects to receive.
def _solve(arr, start, end, thresh, thresh2, thresh3, mixthresh, onecount, treedata, mtree):
    # for small subarrays, use the naive O(n²) approach.
    if end - start <= thresh:
        total_pairs = 0
        for i in range(start, end - 1):
            curr_max = arr[i]
            for j in range(i + 1, end):
                curr_max = max(arr[j], curr_max)
                total_pairs += arr[i] * arr[j] <= curr_max
        return total_pairs, treedata, sorted(arr[start:end])
    # find the index of the maximum element using the segment tree
    # for small-ish subarrays, find the maximum by a linear time search.
    if end - start <= thresh2:
        indx = max(range(start, end), key=arr.__getitem__)
        maxval = arr[indx]
    else:
        (maxval, _, indx), treedata = query_segtree(*treedata, start, end)
    # the number of valid pairs in arr[start:indx]
    x1, (_, *ldata), arr_left = _solve(arr, start, indx, thresh, thresh2, thresh3, mixthresh, onecount, treedata, mtree)
    # the number of valid pairs in arr[indx + 1:start]
    x2, (_, *rdata), arr_right = _solve(arr, indx + 1, end, thresh, thresh2, thresh3, mixthresh, onecount, treedata, mtree)
    # the number of valid pairs involving arr[indx]
    x = x1 + x2 - onecount[start] + onecount[end] - (maxval == 1)
    if (end - indx + 5) * (indx - start + 6) <= thresh3:
        x += sum(1 for i, j in itertools.product(range(start, indx), range(indx + 1, end))
                if arr[i] * arr[j] <= maxval)
    elif min(len(arr_left), len(arr_right)) < mixthresh * (end - start):
        # now calculate the remaining pairs, using the mergetree
        if indx - start < end - (indx + 1):
            for i in range(start, indx):
                # the number of elements arr[j] of arr[indx + 1:start]
                # for which arr[j] * arr[i] <= maxval.
                # or equivalently, arr[j] < 1 + maxval // arr[i]
                cutoff = 1 + maxval // arr[i]
                x += query_mergetree(mtree, *rdata, indx + 1, end, cutoff)
        else:
            for j in range(indx + 1, end):
                cutoff = 1 + maxval // arr[j]
                x += query_mergetree(mtree, *ldata, start, indx, cutoff)
    else:
        arr_left.sort()
        arr_right.sort()
        i = indx - 1 - start
        j = 0
        while i >= 0 and j < (end - indx - 1):
            if arr_left[i] * arr_right[j] <= maxval:
                x += i + 1
                j += 1
            else:
                i -= 1
    if len(arr_left) < len(arr_right):
        arr_left, arr_right = arr_right, arr_left
    arr_left.extend(arr_right)
    arr_left.append(maxval)
    return x, treedata, arr_left
```

Hackerrank does accept this, and it performs well on all inputs I've thrown at
it.

The final big weakness of this program is that it's limited by the size of the
call stack when it operates on sorted or nearly-sorted inputs. This can
particularly be a pain point in Python. You could fix this if you wanted by
manually implementing the recursion using a while loop and a stack.

Here are some more rough timings. `solve` is your version, `solve3` is the first
version in my answer, `solve_merge` is the second and `solve_mix` is the last
(the mixed approach). You can see that `solve_mix` performs much better on the
nearly-sorted input, and `solve3`, `solve_mix` both perform better on the large
random input, but `solve3` is a bit faster.

```
[nav] In [3]: sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 6)
         ...: arr = list(chain.from_iterable((i, 2000 + i) for i in range(1, 2000)))
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve(arr)
735 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [4]: arr = list(chain.from_iterable((i, 5000 + i) for i in range(1, 5000)))
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve3(arr)
1.36 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [5]: arr = list(chain.from_iterable((i, 200000 + i) for i in range(1, 200000)))
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve_mix(arr)
1.87 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [9]: arr = list(range(1, 500000))
         ...: random.shuffle(arr)
         ...: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve(arr)
4.21 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [10]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve3(arr)
1.31 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [11]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve_merge(arr)
8.53 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

[nav] In [12]: %timeit -n 1 -r 1 solve_mix(arr)
2.39 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```